# How to transform fn pointer into closure

Tags: function, rust, closures

For rust functions with no parameter, their function pointers can be passed as closures like this:

```rust
fn foo(){//doing sth}
fn main(){
    thread::spawn(foo).join().unwrap();
};
```

However, how about the functions with parameters? Like:

```rust
fn foo(x:i32,y:i32)->i32{//doing sth with x and y}
fn main(){
    thread::spawn(foo).join().unwrap();
};
```

Which reports error like:

```
4 |     thread::spawn(foo).join().unwrap();
  |     ------------- ^^^ expected function that takes 0 arguments
```

Comment: This is the simplest code.

Comment: If you have two questions, please ask two questions, not one question with two questions in it. Also, it might make sense to use standard terms such as *partial application* and *point-free style* which makes it much easier to understand what you are talking about. (If I understand correctly, that is what you are talking about, but it is somewhat hard to figure out, precisely because you are not using standard terms.)

Comment: But `thread::spawn()` takes an `Fn()` generic, not a function pointer. Just doing `thread::spawn(|| foo(1, 2))` will work.

Comment: @rodrigo Thanks! That works notwithstanding, I just wonder there is an elegent way for functions with parameters. ：）

Comment: Where do you suppose the compiler gets the 2 arguments from if not from you passing them in somehow?

Comment: Are you talking about `move ||`? You don't need parameters, you can just move variables into the closure.

Comment: [tread::spawn](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html) takes exactly one argument, a `FnOnce() -> T`. This is the function it will call when a new thread is created. It doesn't accept a function with parameters, because `thread::spawn` has no parameters to give to the function. Are you trying to move values into the thread? If yes, use a `move || {...}` closure. What are you trying to achieve? I feel like this is an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now I understand what I want to ask is whether rust supports function currying, a skill I encountered in scala before.